# Get error "Object has been deleted or invalidated" when delete Item in realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i load tableview data from realm

```
let tasks = realmManager.objects(ModelTask.self).filter("planId == %@", currentPlan.id)
    datasource = Array(tasks)
    tableViewMain.reloadData()
```

and delete a item when user click delete in tableview

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "删除".localized) {
        [weak self] action, index in
        guard let `self` = self else {return}

        let task = self.datasource[indexPath.row]

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try? realm.write {
            realm.delete(task)
        }

        self.datasource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex:"fe5d5c")

    return [delete]
}
```

and it crashed when realm delete this item.

i got error message reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'

i'm confused this works fine at other view controller.

why not work here?

Edit ----------

solved this problem .

because after i delete this item , i have a log function that used this item.
that's why it always crash.

thank u everyone

Comment: Instead of manually removing items from data source and reloading data, why not use NotificationToken like in the official examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852782/realm-object-has-been-deleted-or-invalidated?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank u very much problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "删除".localized) {
            [weak self] action, index in
            guard let `self` = self else {return}

            let task = self.datasource[indexPath.row]

            let realm = try! Realm()
            try? realm.write {
                realm.delete(task)
                self.datasource = realmManager.objects(ModelTask.self).filter("planId == %@", currentPlan.id)
            }

            tableView.reloadData()

        }
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex:"fe5d5c")

        return [delete]
    }
```

Or you can check isInvalidated before you remove it from data source

```
if !task.isInvalidated{
    self. datasource.removeObject(task)
}
```

Comment: even i remove datasource reset and tableview reload, it still crash . I think the problem is delete a task from realm .